# In what encoding does readpipe return the result of an executed command?

Tags: perl, character-encoding

Here's a simple perl script that is supposed to write a utf-8 encoded file:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (my $out, '>:encoding(utf-8)', 'tree.out') or die;

print $out readpipe ('tree ~');

close $out;
```

I have expected readpipe to return a utf-8 encoded string since `LANG` is set to`en_US.UTF-8`. However, looking at `tree.out` (while making sure the editor recognizes it a as utf-8 encoded) shows me all garbled text.

If I change the `>:encoding(utf-8)` in the open statement to `>:encoding(latin-1)`, the script creates a *utf-8* file with the expected
text.

This is all a bit strange to me. What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: See [Enocde::Locale](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Locale) for how to incorporate locale information.. For your current problem: `readpipe` returns bytes (which will be already encoded as UTF-8). PerlIO layer `>:encoding(utf-8)` will encoded it once more when you print it to file. Solution: Convert the byte string to a Perl string before printing to the file. For example, use `Encode::decode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readpipe` is returning to perl a string of undecoded bytes.  We know that that string is UTF-8 encoded, but you've not told Perl.

The IO layer on your output handle is taking that string, assuming it is Unicode code-points and re-encoding them as UTF-8 bytes.

The reason that the latin-1 IO layer appears to be functioning correctly is that it is writing out each undecoded byte unmolested because the 1st 256 unicode code-points correspond nicely with latin-1.

The proper thing to do would be to `decode` the byte-string returned by `readpipe` into a code-point-string, before feeding it to an IO-layer.  The statement `use open ':utf8'`, as mentioned by Borodin, should be a viable solution as `readpipe` is specifically mentioned in the [`open` manual page](https://metacpan.org/pod/open).

Comment: *" `readpipe` returns to perl a string of bytes"* Please would you link to the documentation that says so?

Comment: @Borodin, I'd love to, unfortunately I'm having trouble finding any docs for it that reflect it's been modified for the post IO-layers world.  I wonder if perl's `-C` command line argument can modify it's behavior, but I've not checked.

Comment: @Borodin [perlunicode: "When Unicode Does Not Happen"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#When-Unicode-Does-Not-Happen)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thank you very much. Since `opendir` is a PerlIO operation I suspect it will be affected by `use open ':utf8'` which is a nice tidy solution

Comment: @Borodin after your `use open ':utf8'` suggestion, I looked at the docs for it.  Finally, a mention of `readpipe` in a modern, IO layered context.  I've updated my answer to reflect this information.